# Lost ".+1" Coq notation in Emacs Proof General Goals buffer

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I wanted to upgrade Emacs (currently 26.1, from emacsformacosx.com, imported directly from High Sierra, with PG 4.5-git) on my Mac running Catalina, and discovered that Apple has made things difficult for Emacs on this version of Mac OS by introducing a "check for malicious software", which seems tricky to bypass.

I reverted to my previous Emacs version, but, since then, the `.+1` notation for SSReflect `nat` doesn't display properly in the Coq Goals buffer of PG (my own Notations are properly managed, though). It's displayed as the standard `succn` constructor instead.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be (FWIW, I'm using the NixOS version of CoQ)?

Comment: Are you sure this is an Emacs issue? What happens if you run the following snippet at the beginning of the file? `From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect. Check (fun n => n.+1 + n.+1).`

Comment: Thanks, Arthur. You're right; this works perfectly. I found that the problem comes from the fact I split my .v file in two, and used `Load` to import the first part of the proof in the second part. Before the `Load`, `.+1`prints fine; after the `Load`, `.+1` is replaced by `succn`. Each part starts with a `From Coq Require Import Init.Prelude Unicode.Utf8. From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect. From mathcomp Require Import fingroup.perm.`.  I guess this redundancy is the source of the problem.